# ZAP websocket scanning

Tags: security, websocket, zap, fuzzing

I have a java application, that only communicates via websocket on port 1234. I'd like to use ZAP for some fuzz testing. The thing is I can't make OWASP ZAP to see my application. If I want to add it as a site, it won't let me because I can add only http sites. I can't scan "ws://127.0.0.1:1234". How can I do that? I checked the ZAP Wiki, and blogs about adding "websocket sites", but they all added it via http, but I can't do that. I tried a few other tools as well, none seems to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We've got some changes in the pipeline that might make this easier. I'll aim to get back to you asap.

Comment: How did this go?